# Magento 1 native gift card module or third party that you can use in physical stores as well as online

Tags: magento-1, third-party-module, gift-card

Be able to deduct balances if a certain amount was used at a physical location etc etc.

Is there anything out there like that?

I know magento has the native gift card standard online use. It would be nice to have physical cards as well that work for both.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Magento are you on? 
Only Magento EE supports gift cards and you would then need a POS that ties directly into Magento to update the gift card $ amount.

If you're on CE and you need a module that does it all for you, check out [magecredit](https://www.magecredit.com/features.html). Their extension comes with API so you can easily take care of updating the store credit / gift card on Magento when someone uses it in a physical store.

Comment: Magento EE 1.14

Comment: I need a good solution for EE. @Haim